# How do you insert a line of text after first few lines

Tags: matlab

I know how to insert a line of text in the beginning of the file which was asked by an other user, but i need to insert a line a file after 8 lines.

```
dlmwrite('extract_f.txt',['first line' 13 10 fileread('extract_f2.txt')],'delimiter','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgetl` to read and skip lines. The following will respect existing content in lines prior to 8 and increase line index, by inserting newlines, to get to line 8 if num of lines is less than that:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'r+t');
nLines = 8; l = 0;
while l < nLines
    l = l + 1;
    s = fgetl(fid); % read line
    if ~ischar(s)||isempty(s)
        fprintf(fid, '\n'); % skip empty lines and last 
    end    
end
fprintf(fid, 'this is line %i', nLines);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Does not work for me, I note that my version of matlab does not mention r+t as a possible argument, but when i change it into r+ simply nothing is written to the file.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin Try r+t even if it is not listed as an argument. Check http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab /ref/fopen.html#inputarg_permission "To open files in text mode, attach the letter 't' to the permission, such as 'rt' or 'wt+'."